# Strange typescript Object.values issue in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, ecmascript-2017

I want to write `Object.values` and TS gives me a visual error (it compiles fine though).

[image: ts error property values does not exist on type "ObjectConstructor"]

I've done the googling, restarted vscode, and that's my `tsconfig.json`.

[image]

Could this be a linter issue? I'm using `eslint` with `eslint-plugin-typescript`. I did check their docs for something akin to a `--lib` option, but nothing. I assume it should read `tsconfig.json`.

Oh, using `select typescript version` set to project's version, not vscode's.

Comment: I fail to see any "visual error". Could you circle it please ?

Comment: also, it seems to me you are missing some commas at the end of each line, don't you ?

Comment: I think you should favor TSLint instead of ESLint if you are working with TypeScript

Comment: updated the question with clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"lib": ["es2018"]` for the moment.

`Object.values` doesn't seem to be included in `es2017`, which seems like a regression. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28166) to track the problem

Comment: Tried it, still erroring. Will update post with tsconfig

Comment: Same, with me, even if I use `"lib": ["dom", "esnext"]`